# Prove a function is a homomorphism of rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

Let $m_1, \ldots, m_n$ be pairwise coprime and $m=m_1m_2\cdots m_n$. Consider the function

\begin{align}
\theta\,\colon\mathbb{Z}_m&\to\prod_{i=1}^n\mathbb{Z}_{m_i}\\
a+m\mathbb{Z}&\mapsto(a+m_1\mathbb{Z}, ..., a+m_n\mathbb{Z})
\end{align}

Prove that this function is a homomorphism of rings.

---

So we must show that for $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}_m$:

1. $\theta(a+b) = \theta(a) + \theta(b)$
2. $\theta(ab) = \theta(a)\theta(b)$
3. $\theta(1) = 1$.

---

1. \begin{align}
   \theta(a+b) = (a+b+m_1\mathbb{Z},\ldots,a+b+m_n\mathbb{Z})
   \end{align}

I have absolutely no idea how to progress here. Haven't done much number theory before.. Can anyone hint in the right direction?

Comment: It has nothing to do with number theory, but with quotient groups. How do you define addition on product of groups?

Comment: I feel like one should also check that the map is well-defined! The similar map $a+3\Bbb Z \mapsto a+2\Bbb Z$ from $\Bbb Z_3$ to $\Bbb Z_2$ is not, for example.

Comment: @GregMartin what does "well-defined" mean?

Comment: Notice that the given definition of the function requires us to make a choice: we have to pick an integer $a$ to represent the residue class $a+m\Bbb Z$, and there are lots of different values of $a$ we could choose ($a$, $a+m$, $a-7m$, etc.). "Well-defined" means that we always get the same answer regardless of which choice we make.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1 we have, i will use general $(a_i+m_i\mathbb{Z})$ for all of them rather than have to write it component wise
$$\theta(a+b+m\mathbb{Z})=(a+b+m_i\mathbb{Z})=((a+m_i\mathbb{Z})+(b+m_i\mathbb{Z}))=(a+m_i\mathbb{Z})+(b+m_i\mathbb{Z})=\theta(a+m\mathbb{Z})+\theta(b+m\mathbb{Z})$$
For the second
$$\theta(ab+m\mathbb{Z})=(ab+m_i\mathbb{Z})=((a+m_i\mathbb{Z})(b+m_i\mathbb{Z}))=(a+m_i\mathbb{Z})(b+m_i\mathbb{Z})=\theta(a+m\mathbb{Z})\theta(b+m\mathbb{Z})$$
and the third one is superflous, it comes naturally from the last 2

Comment: Hi. For 1. how did you separate it? Surely when you add them together you get $a+b+2m_i\mathbb{Z}$ which is not what we had in the first place. Similarly for 2.

Comment: Incorrect, when it comes to quotient rings we have $(a+I)+(b+I)=(a+b)+I$ where $I$ is some ideal in our ring, here of course $I=k\mathbb{Z}$, similarly is for multiplication, that $(a+I)\cdot(b+I)=a\cdot b+I$